# Container element as a parameter to iterate its child elements - Foreach

Tags: javascript

**The consumer function, passing the container to process its elements:**

```
  document.querySelectorAll("section").forEach((sect) => {
    // Iterate through all the sections
    doSomethingOnInnerElements(sect);
  });
```

**The called function on the inner elements:**

```
function doSomethingOnInnerElements(container) {
  Array.from(container).forEach((item) => {  });
  // container.getElementsByTagName("img").forEach((target) => {}
```

There is a problem in the implementation of the **doSomethingOnInnerElements** , can anyone help me to fix it and implement it?

It should be an easy one I think.

Comment: You can't convert a HTMLElement to an array. Use `container.querySelectorAll('img')` to create a list of the images.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to convert a single node into an Array; a node isn't iterable. What are you trying to do, with what HTML?

Comment: @Teemu I also tried:     doSomethingOnInnerElements(sect.elements); I can do everything simply in a function, wanted to separate the job for processing each element.

Comment: If you just described the content of a section element, and what exactly you want to do with it. Just saying "_There is a problem_" is not very helpful.

Comment: It is very easy in languages like C#, now wanted to know how I can do similar stuff in JS. I knew the provided code wrong and was surprised for the down-vote.

Comment: We don't know what exactly you want to implement!

Comment: Wanted just to pass a container element and then iterate through the child nodes in another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heey buddy, hope you're doing good.

You're right it's an easy one.

the querySelectorAll method returns an array of NodeLists which are DOM elements so you can't iterate over their children like you would do with an array (even if you used the Array.from method).

What you need is the **children** property that exists whithin each node. so you function would look like this :

```
function doSomethingOnInnerElements(container){
  Array.from(container.children).forEach((item) => {
    // Your code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, please let me check it, that may do the job.

Comment: Yeah, I'm here if you need any further support

Comment: Getting this: container.children.forEach is not a function

Comment: Yeah my bad. I forgot to add Array.from : 

Array.from(container.children).forEach

Comment: Guess now it is working, thanks, will play more with it.